# Ошибка: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: классы, php

У меня появляется ошибка "Cannot redeclare class system". Это значит, что с классом system что-то не так, а что?

**Добавлено из комментария.**

У меня нет больше таких классоов. Может он вызывается несколько раз?

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if ($class = "system") {
        $class_dir = "system/system.php";
    } else {
        $class_dir = 'system/classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    }
    if (!file_exists($class_dir)) {
        exit("На сайте отсутсвует класс: <b>" . $class . "</b>. Он необходим для работы скрипта.");
    } else {
        require $class_dir;
    }
}
$index = new system;
```

Answer (score 3):

Это значит, что класс с названием `system` в вашем коде пытаются определить второй раз.

```
class system { // определили класс "system"
    ...
}

// ещё немного или много кода
...

class system { // ЧТО, ОПЯТЬ?! - ошибка.
    ...
}
```

**Upd.** Если это копи-пэйст оригинального кода, то тут ошибка:

```
if($class = "system")
```

Ддолжно быть два знака равенства `==` для сравнения. Иначе это просто присваивает переменной `$class` значение `"system"` и `if` всегда будет `TRUE`. Сейчас ваш autoload при любом обращении создаёт класс `system` снова и снова, отсюда и ошибка.

Исправьте на

```
if($class == "system")
```

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Если это копи-пэйст оригинального кода, то тут ошибка:

    if($class = "system")

Два знака равенства надо для сравнения. Иначе это просто присваивает переменной `$class` значение `"system"` и `if` всегда будет `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Нередко эта ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы два или более раз пытаетесь включить один и тот же файл директивой `include` или `require`. В результате PHP парсер пытается снова и снова разобрать уже введенные ранее определения классов и переопределить их.

Чтобы избежать такой ситуации используйте `include_once` или `require_once`.

Comment: Казалось бы, причём здесь Си? =)

Comment: Вот именно причем здесь си я про пхп спрашиваю

Comment: Вообще-то @voldemarus правильно написал, часто подобная ошибка возникает из-за двойного включения одного и того же файла с объявлением класса. Такого нужно избегать.
Пример взят просто из жизни С++ где эта особенность сплошь и рядом встречается.